# XCode localize string Swift

Tags: xcode, string, swift, localization, localized

I am trying to localize a string list.
I have some photos, and for every photo a description of that, and I want to translate the description in another language.

That's the code:

```
var imageList:[String] = ["new_york_city_sky_house_skyscraper_59212_640x1136.jpg","79506M1pZO4U6d12i0Xzf27765gWo71P5061732uthh68xHQ8Dq1yTQ0Bj8p9F45.jpg","iphone 5 wallpaper new york.jpg","New-York-Vintage-Effect-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","Superb-View-Over-New-York-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","New-York-Empire-State-Building-1136x640.jpg","New-York-City-iphone-5s-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","new-york-city.jpg","New-York-By-Day-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","The-Empire-State-Building-New-York-1136x640.jpg"]

var nameList:[String] = ["1","2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

var sentMessage: [String] = ["Description here 1", "Description here 2", "Description here 3", "Description here 4", "Description here 5", "Description here 6", "Description here 7", "Description here 8", "Description here 9", "Description here 10"]
```

I'd like to translate namelist category and sent message category, like this:
"Description here 1" in "Descrizione qui 1", "Description here 2" in "Descrizione qui 2"...

What can I do? I am learning by myself to create an app because I have got some ideas, but I am stucked here...
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can add all localizations in your project info. The file is a `key/value` array. After in your code you can call in Objective-C

```
NSLocalizedString(key:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)
```

like

```
var description = String(format: "%@ %d", arguments: NSLocalizedString("descriptionHere", comment: ""), 2)
```

Here you can see a swift project with internalisation. 
http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/

Comment: I don't know if I do right. I have changed the sentMessage written before in

var sentMessage = String(format: "%@ %d", NSLocalizedString("descriptionHere", comment: "Description here"), 2)

But I have got a error:
'NSInteger' is not convertible to 'String.Index' here:

    @IBAction func showView(){
        let vc = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
        vc.sentMessage = sentMessage[imageIndex]
        showViewController(vc, sender: self)

What can I do?

Comment: %@ %@? Tried and it gave me the same error. It's correct to put in "Localizable.string" descriptionHere = "Description here”;?

Comment: GOOD_MORNING=“Guten Morgen”; like on the url demo.

Comment: textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(“GOOD_MORNING”,comment:“Good Morning”) maybe it's your param imageIndex. try without directly textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(“descriptionHere”,comment:“description here”);

Comment: are you follow the tutoriel http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/ ? and download the sample, you will find out, the sample project works fine.

Comment: Yes I followed it lot of times, it's about two days that I am trying, but I can't applicate it in my project